# How do we get a question from another site migrated to Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

Specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu) over on Stack Overflow.  I'm only a 101 rep user over there but it seems like that question should be over here instead of over there!

Is there anything else I can do on top of flagging it for moderator attention over there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and flagging won't help either. Questions that are older than 60 days [can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/203101). The question you mention was asked in 2012 so migrating it is not an option.

The best you can do is simply ask it yourself here.

Comment: Thanks.  I went on to [copy-paste](http://askubuntu.com/a/872935/344926) it here and attributing original.